# why the predict() function does have different rows in R

Tags: r

I am trying to predict data with linear regression. There is no error but it is kind of weird. I created a linear regression from data1 which has 4000 rows, but i am trying to predict data2 with this linear regression which has only 1000 rows.

Then, i think the result of variable should be just 1000 rows. But it keeps showing the 4000 variables. I do not know what is wrong.

```
model = lm(train$crashes ~ train$latitude)
prediction1 = predict(model, newdata = test)
csv1 = data.frame(Id = c(1:1000), Predicted = prediction1)
```

From this code, I believe it just needs to predict "test" data which has only 1000 rows. But it says that "arguments imply differing number of rows: 1000, 4337" Here the 4337 is from the train data which has 4337 rows.

I think i am doing wrong. How to fix it?

Comment: I'll take a stab in the dark - `test` has 4000 rows, since you asked for `predict(model, newdata = test)`, you get 1 result for each row of `test`

Comment: ```test``` has only 1000 rows. That is why it is weird.... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
model = lm(train$crashes ~ train$latitude)
```

to:

```
model <- lm(crashes ~ latitude, data=train)
```

When using the formula interface, the dataset's name should ideally be specified in `data=` only once instead of like `train$crashes` etc for each variable.

When you call `predict` with `newdata=`, the same `crashes ~ latitude` formula will be interpreted within the new dataset that you have specified.

---

What should have set off alarm bells for you was a warning I got when trying to replicate your issue:

```
train <- data.frame(crashes = rnorm(1000), latitude=sample(1:1000))
test <- data.frame(crashes = rnorm(4377), latitude=sample(1:4377))

model <- lm(train$crashes ~ train$latitude)
prediction1 <- predict(model, newdata = test)
```

> Warning message: 'newdata' had 4337 rows but variables found have 1000
> rows

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was very helpful!! I finally got correct predictions!